# How to apply callback with v8::Arguments?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8

I'm writing a Node.js native module with a function accepting arbitrary length arguments, and it's similar with this in JS:

```js
cb  = function( )
{
  // Receive arguments and do something...
}

foo = function( )
{
  cb.apply({}, arguments)
}

foo([1,2,3])
foo([4])
```

Here, `foo` apply the `cb` with arbitrary arguments.

And the C++ version, according to most Node.js articles about callbacks, would like this:

```cpp
Handle<Value> Foo(const Arguments& args) 
{
  HandleScope scope;

  // Assume that we can get callback from somewhere else.
  Local<Function> cb = getExistingCallback();  

  // Now call it with arbitrary arguments.
  cb->Call(Object::New(), args.Length(), args.Data());

  return scope.Close(Undefined());
}
```

But `Arguments::Data` can only provide `v8::Local<v8::Value>&`, 
not `v8::Handle<v8::Value>*`, so compiler will throw errors.

Because `Local` derived from `Handle`, it's not the problem. I just don't if there is any solution I can use to avoid copy all member from the `Data` to a new array then pass it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Arguments::Data` is not what you want. That data is totally unrelated to the values passed to the function itself, if you look at [the source](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/include/v8.h#4659). `Data` reads from `implicit_args_` while the data you want is in `values_`.

I don't think there is an easy way to get at that information without using `operator[]` so maybe your best bet is the construct the list dynamically? You can use a `std::vector` since its data values are contiguous.

```
int argc = args.Length();
std::vector<Local<Value>> argv;
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
  argv.push_back(args[i]);
}
cb->Call(Object::New(), argc, &argv[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks. The copying loop is what I worried about, because it will execute every time I applying the callback, even though the function already has all information in the `Arguments`. But if this is the only way to do that, I shall obey.

Comment: The only data member in `class Handle<T>` is a `T*` so it should be no different than copying pointers around, so I wouldn't worry about the performance of it. You can certainly call `argv.reserve(argc)` too if you want to avoid multiple allocations.